# When would BASH_SOURCE[1] match $0 when BASH_SOURCE[0] doesn't?

Tags: bash

I've been studying up on Bash lately by reading other people's Bash and in the [BASH3 Boilerplate](http://bash3boilerplate/main.sh) I found this section of code for determining if the script is being run as the main script or not:

```bash
if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" != "${0}" ]]; then
  __i_am_main_script="0" # false

  if [[ "${__usage+x}" ]]; then
    if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[1]}" = "${0}" ]]; then
      __i_am_main_script="1" # true
    fi

    __b3bp_external_usage="true"
    __b3bp_tmp_source_idx=1
  fi
else
  __i_am_main_script="1" # true
  [[ "${__usage+x}" ]] && unset -v __usage
  [[ "${__helptext+x}" ]] && unset -v __helptext
fi
```

I'm not sure how much `__usage` matters except that it's defined *later* in the script.

In testing, I haven't been able to find a circumstance in which `$BASH_SOURCE[1]` is the same as `$0` but `$BASH_SOURCE[0]` is not. What circumstances would actually cause this to be true?

I do know that `$0` can be [unreliable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) but I'm assuming that this pattern has to be frequent enough to not just leave it at:

```bash
if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" != "${0}" ]]; then
    __i_am_main_script="0" # false
else
    __i_am_main_script="1" # true
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when a script is sourced:

```
 $ cat foo
 source bar

 $ cat bar
 echo "\$0 is $0, and here's BASH_SOURCE:"
 declare -p BASH_SOURCE

 $ bash foo
 $0 is foo, and here's BASH_SOURCE:
 declare -a BASH_SOURCE=([0]="bar" [1]="foo")
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried testing that first but must have done something wrong or misread the results; your example worked perfectly.